# commands module problem

Tags: python, command

Hi I'm trying to execute bash command in python by importing commands module.I think I ask the same question here before. However this time it doesn't work.
The script is as below:

#!/usr/bin/python

```
import os,sys
import commands
import glob

path= '/home/xxx/nearline/bamfiles'
bamfiles = glob.glob(path + '/*.bam')

for bamfile in bamfiles:
    fullpath = os.path.join(path,bamfile)
    txtfile = commands.getoutput('/share/bin/samtools/samtools ' + 'view '+ fullpath)
    line=txtfile.readlines()
    print line
```

this samtools view will produce (I think) .txt file

I got the errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./try.py", line 12, in ?
    txtfile = commands.getoutput('/share/bin/samtools/samtools ' + 'view '+ fullpath)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/commands.py", line 44, in getoutput
    return getstatusoutput(cmd)[1]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/commands.py", line 54, in getstatusoutput
    text = pipe.read()
SystemError: Objects/stringobject.c:3518: bad argument to internal function
```

Seems it's the problem with commands.getoutput

Thanks

Comment: This won't fix the problem you are having but a future problem you will have is that commands.getoutput() returns a string and you are calling readlines() on it.  This will fail since readlines() is an operation for a file object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google search for "SystemError: Objects/stringobject.c:3518: bad argument to internal function" brings up several bug reports.  Such as https://www.mercurial-scm.org/bts/issue1225 and http://www.modpython.org/pipermail/mod_python/2007-June/023852.html.  It appears to be an issue with Fedora in combination with Python 2.4, but I am not exactly sure about that.  I would suggest that you follow Michael's advice and use os.system or os.popen to accomplish this task.  To do this the changes in your code will be:

```
import os,sys
import glob

path= '/home/xxx/nearline/bamfiles'
bamfiles = glob.glob(path + '/*.bam')

for bamfile in bamfiles:
    fullpath = os.path.join(path,bamfile)
    txtfile = os.popen('/share/bin/samtools/samtools ' + 'view '+ fullpath)
    line=txtfile.readlines()
    print line
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html)

From the commands documentation:

> Deprecated since version 2.6: The commands module has been removed in Python 3.0. Use the subprocess module instead.

Update: Just realized you're using Python 2.4. An easy way to execute a command is [os.system()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system)

Comment: I agree that he should be using subprocess, but I don't know if it will necessarily fix the problem. Commands is able to be imported which means he is probably using a version of python that supports commands. Therefore it should still work.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the 2.4 version a little late. Update to the post should help some.

Comment: os.system() won't allow him to get the output he needs os.popen() would be a better choice.

Comment: He could just redirect the output to a file. Would be easier IMHO.

Comment: Yeah that would work too.  Just wanted to make it clear that he couldn't just plug in system where getoutput is and expect it to work. :)